# Calculating Dice co-efficient between two random images of same size

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

I am solving a binary segmentation problem. After testing I am using Dice coefficient to calculate the segmentation accuracy between a test mask (ground truth) and the corresponding predicted mask. The predicted mask, after saving in my hard disk, I found, is not binary but of size 256X256X3. So is the ground truth,i.e., of size 256X256X3. It seems all the pixel values are converted to true for the predicted mask (the second image, img2), after Boolean conversion. Why so? Is this code correctly calculating the value of Dice co-eff between them?

```
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import cv2
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg

        def dice_coef(img, img2):
            if img.shape != img2.shape:
                raise ValueError("Shape mismatch: img and img2 must have to be of the same shape.")
            else:
                intersection = np.logical_and(img, img2)
                value = (2. * intersection.sum())  / (img.sum() + img2.sum())
            return value 

        img = cv2.imread('1.png')
        print(img)
        img = np.asarray(img).astype(np.bool)
        print(img)
        print(img.shape)
        print('_'*40)
        img2 = cv2.imread('2.png')
        print(img2)
        img2 = np.asarray(img2).astype(np.bool)
        print(img2)
        print(img2.shape)
        print('%'*40)
        value = dice_coef(img, img2)
        print(value)
```

The output:

```
[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [191 191 191]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [255 255 255]]

 ..., 
 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [157 157 157]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]]
[[[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [False False False]
  ..., 
  [False False False]
  [False False False]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [False False False]
  ..., 
  [False False False]
  [False False False]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [False False False]
  ..., 
  [False False False]
  [False False False]
  [ True  True  True]]

 ..., 
 [[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [False False False]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [False False False]
  ..., 
  [False False False]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [False False False]
  ..., 
  [False False False]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]]
(256, 256, 3)
________________________________________
[[[227 227 227]
  [243 243 243]
  [247 247 247]
  ..., 
  [  2   2   2]
  [  5   5   5]
  [  8   8   8]]

 [[233 233 233]
  [255 255 255]
  [250 250 250]
  ..., 
  [  2   2   2]
  [  4   4   4]
  [  6   6   6]]

 [[206 206 206]
  [252 252 252]
  [253 253 253]
  ..., 
  [  1   1   1]
  [  2   2   2]
  [  4   4   4]]

 ..., 
 [[  5   5   5]
  [  4   4   4]
  [  2   2   2]
  ..., 
  [214 214 214]
  [254 254 254]
  [230 230 230]]

 [[  6   6   6]
  [  5   5   5]
  [  4   4   4]
  ..., 
  [171 171 171]
  [207 207 207]
  [196 196 196]]

 [[  8   8   8]
  [  7   7   7]
  [  5   5   5]
  ..., 
  [ 81  81  81]
  [ 94  94  94]
  [134 134 134]]]
[[[ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]

 ..., 
 [[ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]]
(256, 256, 3)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
0.704061302682
```

[image: img2 : Predicted mask]
[image: img1 : Ground truth]

Answer (score 1):

the dice coefficient is equal to 2 times the number of elements of the intersection on the number of elements of the image + the image 2, in your case the function sum does not give you the number of elements but the sum, just as the logical intersection of numpy doesn't give you equal pixels (see the documentation above) I suggest you modify your code like this :

```
def dice_coef(img, img2):
        if img.shape != img2.shape:
            raise ValueError("Shape mismatch: img and img2 must have to be of the same shape.")
        else:
            
            lenIntersection=0
            
            for i in range(img.shape[0]):
                for j in range(img.shape[1]):
                    if ( np.array_equal(img[i][j],img2[i][j]) ):
                        lenIntersection+=1
             
            lenimg=img.shape[0]*img.shape[1]
            lenimg2=img2.shape[0]*img2.shape[1]  
            value = (2. * lenIntersection  / (lenimg + lenimg2))
        return value
```